# $1/|x|^n$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu $ be a positive Borel measure on $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{d}$ such that $\mu \left( B\left( a,r\right) \right) \leq Cr^{n}$ for some 
$n\in (0,d]$ and for any ball $B\left( a,r\right) $ in $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{d}$. Could you help me to prove that $\int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{d}}\frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n}}d\mu \left( x\right) =\infty $?

My effort: $\int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{d}}\frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n}}d\mu \left( x\right) \geq \int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{d}\backslash B\left( 0,1\right) }\frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n}}%
d\mu \left( x\right) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\int_{B\left( 0,2^{k+1}\right)
\backslash B\left( 0,2^{k}\right) }\frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n}}%
d\mu \left( x\right) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left(
2^{k+1}\right) ^{n}}\mu \left( B\left( 0,2^{k+1}\right) \backslash B\left(
0,2^{k}\right) \right) $.

Comment: What about $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to the $n$-sphere (embedded in the obvious way in $\mathbb{R}^d$)?

Comment: Which page of Stein's book is this from? as @Jose27 remarked, it can't be true as stated. Here's a one-dimensional counterexample ($d=n=1$): $d\mu(x) = \frac{|x|}{x^2+1}|dx|$.

Comment: @PavelM : I wanna learn that Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality (for p=1) is wrong just like lebesgue measure case in Stein book. But now,for a measure that satisfy the above condition.

Comment: @PavelM: How to check that that your measure satisfying $\mu (B(a,r))\leq Cr^n$? Since $d\mu(x)=\frac{|x|}{x^2+1} dx$, then $\mu(x)=\int \frac{|x|}{x^2+1} dx$, right?

Comment: The function $|x|/(x^2+1)$ is bounded (say, by $M$), which implies $\mu(B(a,r))\le 2Mr$. (Integral estimated by supremum * size of the region of integration).

Comment: @beginner: I think your inequality for the measure needs to be reversed.  That is, I think you need $\mu(B(a,r))\geq Cr^n$.  To see why we need this, if it were not the case we could take the trivial measure $\mu=0$.

Answer (score 5):

For every positive $r$ and $n$, 
$$
\frac1{r^n}=\int_r^{+\infty}n\frac{\mathrm ds}{s^{1+n}},
$$
hence Tonelli theorem yields
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac1{\|x\|^n}\mathrm d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\|x\|}^{+\infty}n\frac{\mathrm ds}{s^{1+n}}\,\mathrm d\mu(x)=n\int_0^{+\infty}m(s)\frac{\mathrm ds}{s^{1+n}}=(*),
$$
where, for every nonnegative $s$,
$$
m(s)=\mu(B(O,s)).
$$ 
From this point, it is up to you to select some hypotheses on the function $m$ ensuring that, for the value of $n$ which interests you, the integral $(*)$ converges or that it diverges. As mentioned in the comments, the current hypothesis cannot work.

To make the integral $(*)$ converge at $0$, the control $m(s)\leqslant Cs^a$ when $s\to0$, for some $a\gt n$, is enough. To make the integral $(*)$ converge at infinity, the control $m(s)\leqslant Cs^b$ when $s\to\infty$, for some $b\lt n$, is enough.

On the other hand, if $m(s)\geqslant Cs^n$ when $s\to0$ or when $s\to\infty$, then $(*)$ diverges. This might be the result you had in mind. Note finally that the hypothesis $n\leqslant d$ is irrelevant but that $n$ must be positive.

Comment: I think he needs the condition to be reverse inequality on the measure of the ball, that is $\mu(B(a,r))\geq Cr^n$.  Then using your answer he gets a lower bound of an integral of the form $\int_1^\infty s^{-1}ds$, which explodes.

Comment: @EricNaslund I agree that everything points to this--but this is the OP's job to clear the hypothesis up.